# Populating a column with an existing cell info based on a adjacent populated column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to populate a range, but the range destination always changes. How can I adjust the populated cell range (listed as A3:A12 below) with some kind of variable that will adjust "A12" based on the cell range of column b? such as B3-B19 so A3-A19 fills with A2 in one sheet and B3-B49 on another sheet means that B3-B49 fills with A2 on another sheet without having to change the macro every time...

```
Sub Space_delimiter2col()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With Range(Selection.Cells, Selection.Cells.End(xlDown))
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                   DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                   Space:=True
End With
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A2").Value = "Switch"
Range("A3:A12").Value = Range("B1").Value
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: i don't understan what exactly you mean can u give more details

Comment: Have you tried using a "named" range. Rows inserted or deleted will adjust the range. Is A12 the last line containing data on the sheet ? (which may vary)

Comment: for this sheet A12 is the last, but every sheet will always be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a contiguous series of data in column B, you could replace `Range("A3:A12").Value = Range("B1").Value` with `Range("A3:A" & Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row).Value = Range("B1").Value`.

If column B doesn't have a contiguous series of data, *and* there isn't data below the end of the series you want to fill next to, you can use `Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Row).Value = Range("B1").Value` in place of `Range("A3:A12").Value = Range("B1").Value`.